# Change image depending on sqlite data

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite, listview, imageview

I want to change a imageview depending on the output from my sqlite database, i have a list_row layout which holds the data from the sqlite database. What i want is: if string = something then change the imageview for that listview item.

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    Button btnStartService;
    Context context;
    Database mDB = new Database(this);
    Cursor c;
    SimpleCursorAdapter sCA;
    ListView lv;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        SimpleCursorAdapter sCA;
        btnStartService = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btnStartService.setText("Add test data");
        mDB.open();
        btnStartService.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                //startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, CallService.class));
                //stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, CallService.class));
            }
        });

        ArrayList<String> list1  = new ArrayList<String>();

        ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        c = mDB.getValues();
            c.moveToFirst();
            startManagingCursor(c);

            for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {

            String number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("cname"));

            String action = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("caction"));

            String forwardnumber = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("cnumber"));

            if (action.equals("Block Call")) {
                Log.d("LOG_TAG", "Block call");
                    //Change image to this item

            }else {
                Log.d("LOG_TAG", "Forward call");
                    //Change image
            }
            Log.d("LOG_TAG", number + " " + action + " " + forwardnumber + " ");
                list1.add(number);
                list2.add(forwardnumber);
                c.moveToNext();
            }
            //String []from = {"cname", "caction", "cnumber"};
            //int []to = {R.id.txtNumber,R.id.txtAction,R.id.txtFNumber};
            //sCA = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row, c, from, to);
            //lv.setAdapter(sCA);
            //sCA.notifyDataSetChanged();
            //int []to = {R.id.txtNumber,R.id.txtAction,R.id.txtFNumber};
            //sCA = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row, c, list, to);

        c = mDB.getEmp();
        String []from = {"cname","caction","cnumber"};
        int []to = {R.id.txtNumber,R.id.txtAction,R.id.txtFNumber};
        sCA = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row, c, from, to);
        //ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgAction);
        //iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.one);
        /*if (from[2] == "Block Call") {
            Log.d("LOG_TAG", "Blocked");
        }else {
            Log.d("LOG_TAG", "Forward");
        }*/
        lv.setAdapter(sCA);
        sCA.notifyDataSetChanged();
        c.requery();                           
    } 

    @Override
      protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
      }

    @Override
      protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
      }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_addnumber:
                Log.d("LOG_TAG", "Add number");
                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                CustomDialogFragment addDialog = new CustomDialogFragment();
                addDialog.show(fm, "dialog");
                return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
                Log.d("LOG_TAG", "Open settings");
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PrefrencesActivity.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void doPositiveClick(String etNumber, String etSpinner, String etForwardTo){     
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("cName", etNumber);
        cv.put("cAction", etSpinner);
        cv.put("cNumber", etForwardTo);
        mDB.empInsert(cv);
        c.requery(); 
    }

}
```

Database class:

```
public class Database
{
        public static final String DB_NAME = "callContacts";
        public static final String DB_CONTACTS = "callContactList";
        MyHelper mh;
        Context myCon;
        SQLiteDatabase sdb;
        public Database(Context c) {
            myCon = c;
            mh = new MyHelper(myCon, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        }

        public void open() {
            sdb = mh.getWritableDatabase();
        }

        public class MyHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
            public MyHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version) {
                super(context, name, factory, version);
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
                db.execSQL("create table callContactList(_id integer primary key, cname text,caction text,cnumber text);");
                Log.d("1", "Table Created");
            }

            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }                      
        }

        public void empInsert(ContentValues cv) {
            sdb.insert("callContactList", null, cv);
        }

        public Cursor getEmp() {
            Cursor c = sdb.query("callContactList", null, null, null, null, null, null);
             return c;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings({ "finally", "resource" })
        public boolean CheckNumber(String number) throws SQLException {
            int count = -1;
            Cursor c = null; 
            try {
               String query = "select * from callContactList where cname = " + number;
               c = sdb.rawQuery(query, new String[] {number});
               if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                  count = c.getInt(0);
               }
               return count > 0;
            }
            finally {
               if (c != null) {
                  Log.d("LOG_TAG", "True");
                  c.close();                  
                  return true;
               }else{
                   Log.d("LOG_TAG", "False");
                   return false;
               }
            }
        }

        public boolean verificationNumber(String _number) {
            Cursor c = sdb.rawQuery("SELECT 1 FROM callContactList WHERE cname=?", new String[] {_number});
            boolean exists = c.moveToFirst();
            Log.d("LOG_TAG", Boolean.toString(exists));
            c.close();
            return exists;

        }

        public boolean verificationAction(String _action, String _incomingNumber) {
            Cursor c = sdb.rawQuery("SELECT 1 FROM callContactList WHERE cname=? AND caction=?", new String[] {_incomingNumber, _action});
            boolean exists = c.moveToFirst();
            Log.d("LOG_TAG", Boolean.toString(exists));
            c.close();
            return exists;

        }

        public String getForwardNumber(String _number){
            String forwardNumber = "";
            String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM callContactList WHERE cname="+_number; 

            //SQLiteDatabase sdb = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = sdb.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            if (null != cursor && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                forwardNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("cnumber"));
            } 

            return forwardNumber;

        }

        public Cursor getValues() throws SQLException{
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            Cursor mCursor = sdb.query("callContactList",
                              new String[] {"cname" , "caction", "cnumber"},
                                            null, null, null, null, null);
                    if (mCursor != null) {
                        mCursor.moveToFirst();
                    }

                    return mCursor;



        }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: You have to create your own `SimpleCursorAdapter` and override `getView()`.

Comment: You need to initialize the adapter before your for loop. Then you can reference the ImageView via `(ImageView) adapter.getView(i, null, lv).findViewById(?)` and use the ImageView's method `imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap b)` or `imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable d)`

? is the id you've declared in the xml file of the view that your adapter uses.

Comment: What i did is: `SimpleCursorAdapter sCA = null;` and `ImageView imgView;` then `imgView = (ImageView) sCA.getView(i, null, lv).findViewById(R.id.imgAction);` but i get an FC. Logcat: http://pastebin.com/RdiLT82V

Comment: Well you need to link the adapter to the ListView and it is obviously null since you've explicitly written so. You have to first load the data from the database to the adapter and then use `lv.setAdapter(sCA)` and then change the ImageViews

Comment: I cant seem to figure it out, i still get the FC.

Comment: What causing the FC is: `imgView = (ImageView) sCA.getView(i, null, lv).findViewById(R.id.imgAction);` even tho i call `lv.setAdapter(sCA);` before.

Comment: That can be caused by missinitialized adapter. When initializing it, you need to parse the proper XML, check this out: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context, int, T[])